# AngularJS component in ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, ngcordova

I created a AngularJS component in ES6 like following:

```
import template from 'template.html'

class ctrler {
  constructor ($scope, $cordovaDevice) {
    $scope.title = 'This is from component'
    this.$scope = $scope
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady)
  }

  onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(this.$scope)
  }

  $onDestroy () {
    document.removeEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady)
    console.log('ctrler onDestroy');
  }
}

const cpnt = {
  template: template,
  controller: ctrler
}

export { cpnt }
```

My question is what the `$scope` and the `$cordovaDevice` are local parameter in `constructor(){}`, but I want they become global parameter, so I use `this.$scope = scope`, it's not working.

How do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: It's not ctrler.$scope but this.$scope, for starters. And callback should be bound in order to get proper context.

Comment: Sorry, it's my typing error, actully I use `this.$scope`, but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue is how you're passing in the callback to `document.addEventListener()`. You'll want to bind `this` to the controller's context by adding a call to `bind(this)` to the method when you pass it in.

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this));
```

When you do this, `this.$scope` will correctly refer to `ctrler`'s `this.$scope` when your callback is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `$scope` is not local parameter, it's global.

`onDeviceReady()` function is event listener's callback function, so `this.$scope` means not `ctrler.$scope`, that's the problem.

Thank you for reply and read my question.

Have a good day.